# How to make image button standout when hover without affecting other button position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple script: http://jsfiddle.net/PA9Sf/

I want when I hover a particular button, the size is enlarged and the button stand out on the top of other buttons, instead of affecting the position of other buttons as currently in the jsfiddle above.

```
<img src='http://cdn.mxpnl.com/site_media/images/partner/badge_light.png' />
<img src='http://cdn.mxpnl.com/site_media/images/partner/badge_light.png' />
<img src='http://cdn.mxpnl.com/site_media/images/partner/badge_light.png' />

<script>
jQuery('img').hover(function() {
    $(this).attr('width', '200px');
}, function() {
    $(this).attr('width', '100px');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Don't change the size, instead change border and/or bgcolor

Comment: Add a border like http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/PA9Sf/1/

Comment: @Satpal he specifically asked for button to stand out and not add a border-color

Answer (score 4):

First of all i would highly recommend you to use pure CSS for this.

Second, I think you can achieve this with a [transform](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) scale:

```
img:hover
{
    transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5)); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
}
```

*You can play around with the ratio yourself. Note that i added a marign so the images don't go off-screen*

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PA9Sf/11/)

Answer (score 1):

Changed your code.Try this  **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/XnH3u/)**

**CSS**:

```
.img{
    float:left;
    margin:0px 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top:10px;

}
.img1{
    left:0px;
    z-index:3;

}
.img2{
    left:120px;
     z-index:2;

}
.img3{
    left:240px;
     z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On hover I gave a try with css position as fixed, please try this new jsfillde - http://jsfiddle.net/c3hwf/

CSS Code

```
img{
    width: 100px;
}
img:hover{
    width:200px;
    position: fixed
}
```

HTML Code

```
<p>This is just a test</p>
<img src='http://cdn.mxpnl.com/site_media/images/partner/badge_light.png' />
<img src='http://cdn.mxpnl.com/site_media/images/partner/badge_light.png' />
<img src='http://cdn.mxpnl.com/site_media/images/partner/badge_light.png' />
```

Comment: Also if you keep the position as "absolute" it helps just change the view of the hovered button without affecting other images, additionally you can highlight the button with border or shadow or a different image

Answer (score 0):

[Collection of Creative button Hover and Click Effects](http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeButtons/)

Comment: How much i like these button, i can't see them being relevant to the question. As i can't find the effect the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

width CSS2 :

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PA9Sf/10/)

```
div{width:100px; float:left;border:1px solid #fff; margin-right:5px}
div img{width:100%;}

jQuery('img').hover(function() {
    $(this).css({width : '200px', position:'absolute'});
}, function() {
    $(this).css({width: '100px', position:'static'});
});
```